# Why is my default case statement repeating twice before allowing me to scanf?

Tags: c, switch-statement, printf

i have put down below a small function to check which char the user type. the 'y' and 'n' works fine but i am a bit confused as to why my c code repeats twice before allowing me to type again when i input a different character which i put as my default statement.

```
int any_size_array ()   {

int a=19;
int numb_array [] = {a,22,13,132,153,600};
printf("do you want to add more numbers to the array?\t");
char user;
scanf("%c", &user);
switch(user)    {
case 'y':
    printf("user typed %c\n", user);
    break;
case 'n':
    printf("user typed %c\n", user);
    break;
default:
    printf("please try again\n");
    any_size_array();
    }
```

Comment: If you type `y` followed by a carriage return, you have entered two characters.

Answer (score 1):

Because `\n` is a character, and `%c` does not consume it.  If you want to skip whitespace, try `scanf(" %c", &user)`.

Also, you must *always* check the value returned by scanf.  If `scanf` does not modify the value of `user`, then your program is invoking undefined behavior by attempting to read from an uninitialized variable.  Try:

```
if( scanf(" %c", &user) == 1 ) { ... }
```

Comment: Hi William Pursell, thanks for your help. But i am just wondering that the \n  is still in the case statement and that it calls the function which has a \t. when you check the code on the exe, the printf("do you want to add more numbers to the array?\t");                is showed on a new line. What i am trying to say is that it doesn't make sense over how scanf can interpret the \n as an input...

Comment: It would help if you showed a complete example. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) A tab is not a'y' or an 'n', so the default case statement is applied.  The format string in the default contains a newline, so it is printed.  If you are entering text interactively, the newline is printed on the tty when you hit "return" on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use recursion. Every time you call the `any_size_array()` function all variables are created again and are not related. Use loops for that.
2. Your input has more chars than only the character entered. (new line for example)